# In Audacity, is it necessary to compact or clean-up files to recover disk space?

Tags: audacity

Not intimately familiar with the program yet.

Is there any step necessary to the recover disk space used for temp files, data which has been deleted from the session, etc.?

Just wondering, because I have noticed it uses a rather unconventional file structure/style to store the audio data, and also, while most NLEs do their cleanup automatically, I know sometimes features like that get back-burnered in FOSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it seems that Audacity wipes out the temp file as soon as there is a permanent file. See this thread: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=70974